# Meaning of symbol on LED screen price tag

Tags: led

I wanted to know the meaning of a particular globally-used standardized symbol printed on the price tag of every led screen.
Here is the symbol:

[image]

Comment: This means a guy named Larry Reynolds is trapped inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a quality mark, certification mark, introduced by an American organization called Underwriters Laboratories. `UR` is an abbreviation for `UL Recognized`. I know too little about it myself so I can only refer to a Wikipedia article on it: [Recognized Component Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recognized_Component_Mark)

Comment: It may as well be a knockoff of UR mark. Like China Export CE mark is almost identical to European CE mark.

Comment: I agree that the mark in the question is slightly different from the original one, which is at least 'interesting'.

Comment: @jippie: Thanks. Actually, I manually typed the letters as I was unable to find a bigger image of that logo. It's the same one which you have suggested here.