# Identify Logos on Bridge Rectifier

Tags: identification, rectifier

This is one of two bridge rectifiers recovered from a failed LED lamp.

[image: Bridge Rectifier]

I've seen the 'backwards R' before but don't know what it means/identifies. The other logo on the left is one I've never seen before. Can anyone identify/explain either of these? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try googling "DB104 bridge rectifier"?

Comment: @Joe, yes, and I looked at several data sheets trying to find the logo on the left, to no avail.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49780/meaning-of-symbol-on-led-screen-price-tag

Comment: Thanks, @jippie, I up voted your reply to that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be Russian, or sold by Russians.  At least, I find Russian parts suppliers listing bridge rectifiers with the same logo.  For example at this odd URL with spaces in it: http://radimexbg.com/index.php?pid=1%20%20%20%20%20%209122   or same part at http://radiodetali.spb.ru/diody-i-diodnye-mosty/most-diodnyjj-kbu6m/id190/

I hope you read Russian!  Google translate didn't turn up any obvious manufacturer's name, so far.   But having gotten this far, my curiosity will not rest...

UPDATE:
Aha got it!   Yangzhou Yangjie Electronics Co Ltd
http://www.21yangjie.com/en/

PDF datasheet for the other part (not the one in the original question): http://images.ihscontent.net/vipimages/VipMasterIC/IC/YANG/YANGS00160/YANGS00160-1.pdf

Comment: how on Earth did you track that down? Have you just seen parts with that logo before? Anyway, good show!

Comment: (blows final wisps of smoke off hot googling fingertips) Well, that was the hardest Google search I've done in a long time.

Comment: Thanks. @Peter, I think this was the more difficult question to answer, so with thanks to you as well, I'm giving the laurels to Daren.

Comment: Peter is right about the reverse "UR" so I upvoted :)  Amazing, how we can come together on a site like this and solve mysteries.

Comment: Yup well done dude +1

Comment: @DarenW, no question. I wish I could choose two winners, but I did up vote Peter too.

Answer (score 7):

The reverse "UR" logo is an Underwriters Laboratories component recognition mark. (UL http://www.ul.com/ ) is a US standards certification organization.

The other logo is probably the manufacturer's logo, but I don't recognize it.

Comment: UL have an index of logo's.... just trying to find it ...I think it was the UL white book ?

Comment: Ok... I think my memory is faulty... it's not in the white book ... but i m trying to read it on my tablet and it's not fun. For ref http://www.ul.com/global/documents/offerings/perspectives/regulators/2012%20WB%20FINAL.pdf

Comment: http://database.ul.com/cgi-bin/XYV/template/LISEXT/1FRAME/glocids.html the index's of trade marks ..... not the most easy to use index, but if your desperate...

Comment: @Spoon, that is very interesting, in a "late night browsing" sort of way. I searched through all the linked UL directories that made sense, and found Yangzhou… in the  third "Recognized Components" volume. But if I hadn't known the name of the company courtesy of DarenW, I would have had to visually scan every page for the logo. So yeah, if you're desperate. Still, fun to see, so thanks.